# Sudden termination due to lack of fund

Tags: termination, fulltime

I joined a job where the position was mentioned as full time. But my manager said that I am terminated with the current month due to lack of funds to support my position. So I have the below questions

1. Can I ask my Manager about how/why my position is terminated since I was mentioned in the beginning that it is a full time job?
2. How to face this sudden termination problem/How to handle this situation?

Comment: "Full time" just means 40 or so hours a week. It is entirely different from "permanent" vs "temporary".

Comment: For future job conversations, you were "laid off", not "fired". The former has no negative connotations for you, the latter implies you might have been fired for a reason. "Terminated" is technically true but ambiguous about the reasoning, so always say you were laid off.

Comment: I have seen this situation several times... every time that there were sudden unexpected layoffs the company either sold(for assets/clients) or closed within 6 months and everyone (or almost everyone) working there was let go.

Comment: Where did this happen? Please tag your locality inside your question, as different local legislation dictates your rights in this situation.

Comment: @David K It depends on the region too. In the Nordic countries, there is little difference whether you were fired or laid off. Both have equal and very negative connotations. But it's also a cultural difference, as co-operative negotiations are more commonly used as a tool to discard low performers and those with too high salary/age. Since there is no at-will here, it is the only way to accomplish the same end result of keeping salaries in check and low enough.

Comment: @JuhaUntinen the Nordic countries practice age discrimination ? and redundancy is considered the same as fired for cause are you sure?

Comment: @Neuromancer Yes, ageism is very rampant. This is extremely pronounced in IT, where basically you are first to be laid off if you are over 40. And you will have a hard time to get a new job due to age. When Nokia laid off thousands of Master's degree engineers with decades of experience, most of them were unemployed for years. Some still are, or they changed fields.

Comment: Yes, prospective employers do not see the difference at all whether your previous employer ran out of money or you had some repeat gross misconduct. They just see that you are currently unemployed and think: "This guy is not skilled because he is unemployed. Red flag.". So in practice, almost everyone changes jobs while still employed. And then that reinforces the perception further, which leads to only currently employed candidates being interviewed. So you don't even get the chance to explain in an interview that your previous employer ran out of money.

Comment: @JuhaUntinen that surprising thought the Swedish TUC would be more on that I will have to mention that to my mate who is chair of UNI

Answer (score 12):

> Can I ask my Manager about how/why my position is terminated since I
>   was mentioned in the beginning that it is a full time job?

If you don't understand, then you should ask.

Remember that in most locales "full time" doesn't mean "permanent" or "forever" or "even if we run out of money to pay you". Usually it refers to the number of hours worked in a week (as opposed to "part time").

> How to face this sudden termination problem/How to handle this
>   situation?

Depending on your locale, you should immediately file for unemployment benefits and begin looking for a new job.

You should also check any contract, local laws and employee handbook to determine what notice pay you are due - this may depend on how long you have been employed.

Answer (score 3):

Bascially it is as your boss described it.  They not longer have the funds to justify your position.  This is typically referred to as a layoff, or sometimes a reduction in force(RIF).  Different companies and countries will call it differently.

On the plus side, you were not terminated for cause and should receive a letter you can use to apply for unemployment, if your region has that.

Answer (score 2):

Sadly this is not that unusual in the software industry.   I was hired on a job a couple of years ago and 2 months later the customer cut the project's budget by 85% which resulted in all but one developer and 2 managers being laid off.  It was simply a matter of they had no other positions for us and the company couldn't pay us if no one was paying them.  They did explain that to us, however.

If they have not explained the situation to you, I don't see how there is any harm in asking.   If you are being laid off, the situation isn't going to get worse.

As to how to handle the situation, there's not much to do but start searching for something new.   This can be a long, frustrating process, but sooner you start, the better off you will be.  One thing to watch out for, some people can fall into a depression when they are in this situation, do whatever you can to keep motivated.

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes I'm at the verge of depression. But I will surely make myself stable and start my next job hunt :-)